# Securing applications hosted on openshift using SSO

Tags: oauth-2.0, openshift, single-sign-on

We have a bunch of applications that are deployed on openshift. For e.g. we have a Project A and it has three applications.

Is there a way in openshift where we can configure it(by creating a new application) to be authenticated so that when users try to access these applications, they will be routed to the login page and will be authenticated?

Comment: To be fair, I haven't looked into this too much in the past, but you _should_ be able to create a Service Account, and then specify that when setting up OAuth: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.3/authentication/using-service-accounts-as-oauth-client.html

Comment: Ah ok, do you think we can create an API gateway in openshift and use that to secure access to other applications?

Comment: Pls check oauth-proxy if it helps!